# Remove html tags in python without HTML formatters

Tags: python

I am trying to remove HTML tags from text in Python. The issue is with the format of the tags present. Ex:

```
[click internet options div on the right]

div - is the HTML tag
```

Expected:

```
[click internet options on the right]
```

It does not have the format like <> etc. Currently I manually created a list of HTML tags and removing it using the "not in". Is there a better way to clean this. P.S I am not asking for the code as such, any suggestions on the approach would be great.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to remove (an output example would help).

Comment: @MichaelButscher added the expected op

Comment: You will at least need a list of the html tags to remove as there is no other way to identify them in the input data. A more efficient way to do the cleaning then are regular expressions like e.g. `re.sub(r"\b(?:div|b|span)\b", "", data)` to remove `div`, `b` and `span` from `data` string. With refinements, also double spaces remaining here can be removed.

Comment: Forgot the important `r` prefixing `"\b(?:...`, added it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, but you will need a list of the HTML tags you want to remove. Take a look to [re.sub documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub), it will help you to write your regexp, like this one:

```
re.sub(r"(div|section|aside)", "", toCheck)
```

The first parameter is the pattern, the second the replacement (in this case nothing) and then, the third, the string to check.